# Randomize Random Array Quicksort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random, quicksort

I am in my first year in Computer Science and I learned that you can avoid the worst case scenario of QuickSort by randomizing the array before you start sorting.

But does this also apply when the input is already random? I would think that there is an even chance of randomly placing the array in order than shuffling it more?

Comment: If somebody gives you a deck of cards that's already shuffled, what's the likelihood that shuffling them again will put them in order? Randomizing an already-randomized array gives you equal likelihood of every possible outcome. There are very few arrangements that give Quicksort serious problems. The likelihood of randomly shuffling an array to obtain one of those arrangements is very, very small.

Comment: Who told you to randomize the array?!  It's far less work to randomize the choice of pivot rather than randomize all the data, and randomizing the pivot on average will work well whether the data are ordered or unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomizing to avoid O(something) is a purely academic nuance. `Math.random()` is so time-comsuming that the effect will be negative.

What really matters is

- total number of operations performed
- avoiding random access to memory to avoid cache misses (google something about cache hit ratio).

In this terms, good sorting algorithms are

- Yarroslavkij's dual-pivot quicksort, which is default in java sort. This one resolves worst-case scenario in a much better deterministic way by selecting two pivots and splitting the array into 3 parts.
- Radix sort, Bucket sort or derivates, in my point of view the fastest algos possible, however using `2n` memory.